# Javascript remote JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I got a problem fetching the JSON, it works fine with static sites, but not with dynamic sites.

I tried JSONP too also, but I get the error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

What could be the source of error as JSONP makes the request, but can't get the variable?

```js
$.getJSON('http://imdb-fetch.herokuapp.com/movie/tt5463162', function(data) {
  console.log(data.message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ???? really hard to understand the problem you're facing on.

Comment: yes its not solved by using jsonp too


i am able to fetch json but not able to access it